# Bluetooth disconnect immediately after connecting

Tags: audio, bluetooth, bluez

I am using Manjaro Linux.  All bluetooth devices have stopped connecting to my computer.  Neither headset nor smartphone will connect for more than a few seconds.

`bluetoothctl` shows the following output

```
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 08:D4:6A:13:E8:3E Connected: no
```

The initial pairing works, but it will not connect again after that first moment of connection, showing a KDE "setup failed" and "connection failed" dialogs when I use the graphical interface.